# How to check if the form on my HTML landing page is working properly on Facebook & Instagram mobile apps?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have added a form on HTML page which sends me an email after submission.

I want to make sure it works on ALL MOBILES, specially on the Facebook and Instagram mobile apps. I have checked it on my phone and I have used the chrome developer tool.

**Is this the best way to have a form on HTML page? Or is there a better way?**

**The test page:** https://www.zidan-dxb.com/test.html

**HTML Code:**

```
    <form id="my_form2" onsubmit="submitForm2(); return false;">
     <p><input class="form" id="n2" placeholder="Name" aria-label="Name" required></p>
     <p><input class="form" id="e2" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" aria-label="Email"></p>
     <p><input class="form" id="t2" placeholder="Phone" type="tel" aria-label="Phone" required></p>
     <textarea class="form" id="m2" placeholder="Write your message here" aria-label="Message" rows="4"></textarea>
     <p><input class="formbut" id="mybtn2" type="submit" value="Send"> <span id="status2"></span></p>
    </form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    function _(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function submitForm2() {
        _("mybtn2").disabled = true;
        _("status2").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("n2", _("n2").value);
        formdata.append("e2", _("e2").value);
        formdata.append("t2", _("t2").value);
        formdata.append("m2", _("m2").value);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST", "https://www.zidan-dxb.com/alfurjan/form2.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                if (ajax.responseText == "success") {
                    _("my_form2").innerHTML = '<p>Thanks ' + _("n2").value + ', your message has been sent.</p>';

                } else {
                    _("status2").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("mybtn2").disabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send(formdata);
    }
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
    <?php
if( isset($_POST['n2']) && isset($_POST['e2']) && isset($_POST['t2']) && isset($_POST['m2']) ){
    $n2 = $_POST['n2']; // HINT: use preg_replace() to filter the data
    $e2 = $_POST['e2'];
    $t2 = $_POST['t2'];
    $m2 = nl2br($_POST['m2']);
    $to = "h@zidan-dxb.com";    
    $from = "z@zidan-dxb.com";
    $subject = 'Contact Form Message alfurjan';
    $message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n2.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e2.' <br><b>Tell:</b> '.$t2.' <p>'.$m2.'</p>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Simple test it with app and you can use google dev(F12) for simulate mobile device.

Comment: I have tested it on the google dev tool it works fine. But I want to make sure the form works fine on Facebook and Instagram Apps on phones. I have tried with my phone it worked. I am not sure if this is the best way to create a form on HTML page. please let me know if there is a better way. thank you

Comment: fyi: `"If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered"` ~ you don't therefore need multiple `&& isset() ` in the `if` clause!

Comment: Thank you RamRaider, to be honest, I know only HTML & CSS I have copied the PHP codes from the internet. Please tell me how the code should be instead? and is this a good way to add a form to an HTML page? or there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can test that in Developer Mode present in google chrome.

**Ctrl + Shift + I**  will open up developers tools then press **Ctrl + Shift + M** and this will open Device Toolbar where you can check your website for different resolutions and devices

Comment: I totally forgot of a shortcut that does the same thing described above (F12)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have already tried the Chrome Developer Mode. However, I need to make sure this form works on Facebook and Instagram apps on mobile. Also do you know if this is the best way to have a form on HTML page? thank you